# Collaborative notepad app for android

Tags: android, notepad

i want to develop a notepad alike app where initially all those who subscribed my pad can get my contents synchronized in real time but they can't edit my pad's contents **and** later on i want to give collaborative write access to every client.

There are so many references regarding sync between dropbox with phone **or** within yours multiple devices but didn't find anything useful.

**EXAMPLE:** Etherpad for desktop but mine is for android.

(Q1) How can client subscribe my pad.
(Q2) How can i setup a server which once get my pad's content will automatically  broadcast to  all the clients.
(Q3) How can i control conflicts for multiple write access between clients.

Please give some references to start with..thanks

Answer (score 0):

About Q1 and Q2 it will depend on the tool you choose for the server. But it will end being a socket. I recommend reading this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/
About Q3, you will have to create a policy for this. One aproach is doing like Google Docs: keep the cursor location on server and broadcast to all clients, when another client changes the place your cursor is, your cursor changes along the change (remove or add text)